# Convert Excel to PDF using Applescript (save as PDF)

Tags: excel, macos, pdf, applescript

I have an .xlsx file and I want to save it in PDF format using Applescript. I have thoroughly googled this but apparently there are a million issues.

I would like something to save as an .app, where the `...` in the code would be replaced by a code chunk to convert the active workbook to PDF, like this:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    open  "/somedirectory/workbook1.xlsx"
    ...
end tell
```

Answer (score -1):

Found it! Here is the answer:

http://blog.krugazor.eu/2010/01/applescript-batch-saving-to-pdf/

The following is cited from the link above:

"Basically, what it does is simulate keystrokes and clicks. That allows you to do anything a user would be able to do.

Without further ado, the AppleScript to batch save to pdf a bunch of excel files using the print dialog!"

```
on open some_items
    repeat with this_item in some_items
        try
            tell application "Microsoft Excel"
                activate
                open this_item
                tell application "System Events" to tell process "Microsoft Excel"
                    --Bring up print window
                    keystroke "p" using command down
                    --Choose "PDF" > "Save as PDF"
                    click (menu button "PDF" of window 1)
                    click (menu item 1 of menu of menu button "PDF" of window 1)
                    delay 2
                    -- Choose the desktop as save locaton (Command-D)
                    keystroke "d" using command down
                    --Save
                    keystroke "s" using command down
                    keystroke return

                    -- wait and close
                    delay 3
                    keystroke "w" using command down
                end tell
            end tell
        end try
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"
        open desktop
    end tell
end open
```

Comment: For posterity, could you include the relevant parts of the link which you found useful in your answer? That way, if the link goes down, changes, etc., your answer won't be rendered useless. Many thanks.